# Best source control development tool for Windows / .NET

Tags: .net, version-control, ide, repository

What are your recommendations to use as a source control, project repository for a Windows - .NET development environment (two coders, possible one using the system)?

Addition: also the team includes three developers. One Visual Basic 6.0 moving to .NET, myself in .NET, and one web developer (PHP, JavaScript, etc.)

The system I am looking for would be something that easily integrates into the IDE of Visual Studio.

Comment: I have had great success with Mercurial on small teams - however, the current IDE integration is not optimal.

Comment: SVN works fine for small teams

Comment: @Oded: I can't image VSS being "best" for anything. It is only positive feature is being better than no SCM.

Comment: @Richard - Where did I say "best"? I just said it was _a_ SCM.

Comment: @Richard - See the edits to the title. It originally said "Best source safe development tool..."

Comment: @Oded: I see... but I think my comment still stands (as guide in comparing VSS with other tools).

Comment: @Richard - Fair enough, though with the edit, mine doesn't and will be deleted forthwith.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Team Foundation Server](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/team-foundation-server) is probably the most integrated into Visual Studio.

However, I personally love [Kiln](http://www.fogcreek.com/kiln/) (which also integrates nicely into VS).  This is nice for a small team, being hosted and very elegant and easy to use.

Other options include [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) and [Git](http://git-scm.com/).  However, without knowing more requirements, it's difficult to suggest the "best" option for a small .NET team.  Self-hosted vs. hosted for you is probably the largest factor in making your decision...

Comment: TFS makes no sense for a small team and the cost is prohibitive.

Comment: @Tim: 2010 adds quite a bit of support for small team usage, including dramatically simplified management and installation.  Pre-2010, I completely agree with this sentiment, but as of 2010, it's not so bad...

Comment: its probably going to be just myself using it. someone else in the company has suggested Mercurial  and get. however im looking for a pretty easily integrated, gui type system to handle it for myself. i dont know how effective mercurial would be for this, each coder works on his own programs, not much sharing (3 coders). i used to use visual source safe but it ate some forms so that relationship came to an end

Comment: also - the 3 coders. 1 works in vb6, moving things to .net. i work in .net only, using vb and c#, and the other code is webdesign, php, html etc.

Comment: @Jeff: The Kiln+FogBugz bundle is great for this, and its reasonably priced... It's what I'm currently using on my project.

Comment: @Jeff: Most source control systems are code-neutral, so it really doesn't matter...

Comment: @Reed - ok, I stand corrected - I have not looked at it in a while and it is nice to see MS improving for more user classes.

Comment: @reed, right, i added additions to my original question. i have seen a few that seem to be command line operated. im not really interested in that. i liked the ease of visual source safe, ill give kiln and tfs a look thanks!

Comment: @Jeff: Kiln is nice if you install VisualHg and the Kiln tools, otherwise, it's not so great.  SVN is the same way - install TortoiseSVN or AnkhSVN, etc.

Comment: someone on the team was looking at kiln currently.. have you ever installed this on a server or used the hosted servers? @reed thanks

Comment: @Jeff: I'm using the hosted solution (with FogBugz bundled) - it's fantastic.

Comment: i like what i see with kiln - thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) and any Visual Studio plugin for svn: [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) or [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/).

### EDIT:

Quite some time has passed. If I were to answer this question today, I'd strongly recommend using [git](http://www.git-scm.com/). I personally use it even when working alone. I didn't try to integrate it into Visual Studio, but standalone app [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) serves me well. If you never used git before I'd recommend reading [Pro Git](http://www.git-scm.com/book) book (it's free). Evening or two spent on it will pay off.

Comment: +1 We use Tortoise ourselves and just use the Explorer integration to check our projects in.  I've tried the VisualSVN VS Plugin and it works pretty nicely too.

Comment: @alpha-mouse is it can provide code protection??

Comment: @AminM, sorry, code protection against what threat?

Comment: @alpha-mouse I search way for protect my code against theft ing, can source control do it ? Or I should use other program along with SVN software?

Comment: @AminM no version control system will provide such protection _by itself_. But I believe you can use any popular VCS in a secure manner so that it won't make you _any more_ exposed if you are employing proper security measures. You may find http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9162/is-it-possible-to-encrypt-your-java-source-code-and-still-have-it-readable-wri and https://lavag.org/topic/9891-encryption-and-svn/ interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Perforce](http://www.perforce.com). Free version allows something like 2-users, 5 workstation. Paid version is reasonable as far as configuration management tools go.

Answer (score 2):

Give a try to [Plastic SCM Community Edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691831/plastic-scm-is-it-the-right-solution). It is a free version control system for up to 15 users, commercially supported, distributed (if you want to, it can be centralized) and with integrated diff and merge tools.

- The entire GUI is totally [integrated with Visual Studio](http://www.plasticscm.com/features/third-party-integrations/visual-studio-integration.aspx).
- Branching and merging can be tracked visually with the [branch explorer](http://www.plasticscm.com/features/visualization.aspx).
- [XDiff and XMerge](http://codicesoftware.blogspot.com/2010/07/move-support-in-diff.html) for diffing and merging code supporting refactors.
- Cool features like the ["method history" support](http://codicesoftware.blogspot.com/2010/12/announcing-method-history.html). (Note: also [available for SVN](http://codicesoftware.blogspot.com/2011/01/method-history-for-subversion-is-here.html)).

Hope it helps.