# Can i rollback my vb project?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, backup, rollback

I don't know how but it started with errors saying resources is not of my or something like that then i just went through all the errors and vb automatically fixed it which lead to errors like this

"   To prevent possible data loss before loading the designer, the following errors must be resolved:

```
1 Error
```

Ignore and Continue
    Why am I seeing this page?

The designer cannot process the code at line 60, please see the Task List for details. The code within the method 'InitializeComponent' is generated by the designer and should not be manually modified. Please remove any changes and try opening the designer again.     Go to code

Instances of this error (1)

1. 2Drectangle.Designer.vb Line:60 Column:1   Show Call Stack

   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.XML.CodeDomXmlProcessor.ParseXml(String xmlStream, CodeStatementCollection statementCollection, String fileName, String methodName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomParser.OnMethodPopulateStatements(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.CodeDom.CodeMemberMethod.get_Statements()
   at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.TypeCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeTypeDeclaration declaration)
   at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.DeferredLoadHandler.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextBufferDataEvents.OnLoadCompleted(Int32 fReload)

Help with this error

Could not find an associated help topic for this error. Check Windows Forms Design-Time error list

Forum posts about this error

Search the MSDN Forums for posts related to this error

"

so I just closed it there was no popup to save it i think it autosaved and now im really worried there's 3 weeks worth of work in this project which is due tomorrow >.<

Comment: Oh, source control can to miracles, really.

Comment: Windows File History to the rescue! Only if you enabled it before the incident of course.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built in mechanism for rolling back your project No (aside from clicking `Edit > Undo` in Visual Studio but this will only undo what has been done since you opened the project)

Generally people use Source Control software which does this for you.

If you don't have access to any source control software ([and there is no good reason for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716071/best-source-control-development-tool-for-windows-net)) then you should make your own backup every so often.

This doesn't help you now but it is a lesson for the future.

Comment: +1. Actually another +1 should go to you for the last sentence.